# Ubuntu tablet convergence on samsung galaxy note 8.0 gt-5110

Tags: samsung, tablet, compatibility

Is my samsung galaxy note 8.0 (gt-5110) compatible with the new Ubuntu convergence tablet software, I would like to give it a spin :-)